# Retrieving the device name of the phone

Tags: android

How can I retrieve the device name on the phone ?
I dont mean the model - for example: GT I9500 (Galaxy S4), but the actual device name, that is being used for Bluetooth, Hotspot with Wi-Fi connections and such...
(The phone's name)

(For example, the default device name for new Galaxy S4 devices is: "Galaxy S4").

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method will help you to get device name,hope it helps you.All the best

```
public String getDeviceName() {
  String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
  String model = Build.MODEL;
  if (model.startsWith(manufacturer)) {
    return capitalize(model);
  } else {
    return capitalize(manufacturer) + " " + model;
  }
}


private String capitalize(String s) {
  if (s == null || s.length() == 0) {
    return "";
  }
  char first = s.charAt(0);
  if (Character.isUpperCase(first)) {
    return s;
  } else {
    return Character.toUpperCase(first) + s.substring(1);
  }
}
```